# Button renders incorrectly in Internet Explorer 7 - IE7 specific CSS fix required

Tags: html, css, plsql, internet-explorer-7

We have an online system that uses plsql to deliver content to users. The underlying system has its own styling for certain elements but most of it were are able to override with a seperate css file for specific clients. Currently I am working on a section for one of our clients where the plsql pulls out all of the current vacancies on a page. The html itself is hard-coded into the plsql procedure so I have to work with it how it comes out of the system. If you look at the image below (shown in Firefox) you will see one of many jobs that are presented on a page. All jobs have the same html structure (shown below in fig 1). The way I have managed to render it in Firefox and all other browsers is perfect (as shown by the image) however in IE7 it looks terrible (fig 2). Any ideas what I can do /  add to my css to make it render correctly in IE7? The computed CSS from Firebug can be found at the bottom of this page.

FIG 1
[image: Fig 1]

HTML

```
<div class="jobpost Job Postings">
<div class="template_image"></div>
    <div class="jobpost_body">
        <h2>
        <a href="/icamstest/wd/plsql/wd_portal.show_job?p_web_site_id=4227&p_web_page_id=156962">Head of Operations</a>
        </h2>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing tincidunt males uada. Aenean metus lorem, lacinia est. Maecenas sit amet magna rhoncus imperdiet. Quisque consectetur lacinia felis, posumassa fermentum vel. Morbi metus nibh, tincidunt luctus hendrerit, iaculis sed velit.
        <br>
        <br>
        Suspendisse potenti. Praesent sit amet rhoncus nisi. Etiam tristique velit ut felis ultrices pulvinar. Ut elit leo, condimentum nec consectetur non, tincidunt malesuada lorem.
        </p>

        <p class="jobpost_classifications">
            <span class="jobclass even location">
                <span class="jobclass_type">Location:</span>
                <span class="jobvalue">  Birmingham</span>
            </span>
            <span class="jobclass uneven date_on">
                <span class="jobclass_type">Date posted:</span>
                    26/11/2012 
            </span>
            <span class="jobclass even date_off">
                <span class="jobclass_type">Closing Date:</span>
                    31/01/2013 
                </span>
            <span class="jobclass uneven refno">
                <span class="jobclass_type">Ref No:</span>
                    85 
                </span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="jobpost_nav">
        <p>
            <a class="apply_direct" title="Apply For Position ? (Head of Operations)" href="/icamstest/wd/plsql/wd_portal_cand.form?p_web_site_id=4227&p_web_page_id=156962">Apply For Position ? </a>
            <a class="send_a_friend" title="Send a friend (Head of Operations)" href="/icamstest/wd/plsql/wd_portal.send_a_friend?p_web_site_id=4227&p_web_page_id=156962">Send a friend</a>
        </p>
</div>

</div>
```

FIG 2

[image: Fig 2]

CSS

```
        div.jobpost {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    div.jobpost {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        font-size: 100%;
        outline: 0 none;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    div.jobpost div.jobpost_body {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    div.jobpost_body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #icams_inserted {
        color: #6D7A7E !important;
        font-family: Arial !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        font-style: normal !important;
        font-weight: 400 !important;
    }
    html.ext-strict body {
        text-align: left !important;
    }
    body {
        color: #6D7A7E;
    }

    .jobpost_body h2 {
        font-family: Arial,'Adamina',serif !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.25;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        color: #606163;
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: Arial,'Adamina',serif;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 28px;
    }


    div.jobpost_body h2 a {
        border: 0 solid #FF0000;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 10px 0 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .not-ie a, .not-ie a > * {
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    a, a > * {
        color: #6D7A7E;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        font-size: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        outline: medium none;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }


    div.jobpost_body h2 a {
        border: 0 solid #FF0000;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 10px 0 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .not-ie a, .not-ie a > * {
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    a, a > * {
        color: #6D7A7E;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        font-size: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        outline: medium none;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    div.jobpost_body p.jobpost_classifications {
        border: 0 none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 0;
        width: 200px;
    }
    div.jobpost_body p {
        clear: none !important;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }
    div.jobpost_body p {
        clear: left;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
    .jobpost_body p {
        color: #6D7A7E;
        font: 400 12px/19px Arial;
    }
    p {
        padding-top: 10px !important;
    }
    p {
        margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    }


    .jobclass {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    .jobclass_type {
        color: #6D7A7E;
        font: 700 12px/18px Arial;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }


    .jobclass_type {
        color: #6D7A7E;
        font: 700 12px/18px Arial;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }


    div.jobpost_nav {
        float: left;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0 6px !important;
        width: 100%;
    }


    div.jobpost_nav p {
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }


    div.jobpost_nav a.apply_direct, div.jobpost_nav a.job_basket, div.jobpost_nav a.send_a_friend {
        padding: 8px 14px !important;
    }
    div.jobpost_nav a.apply_direct, div.jobpost_nav a.job_basket, div.jobpost_nav a.send_a_friend {
        float: left;
    }
    div.jobpost_nav a.apply_direct, div.jobpost_nav a.job_basket, div.jobpost_nav a.send_a_friend {
        padding: 0 20px 0 0 !important;
        width: auto;
    }
    .not-ie a, .not-ie a > * {
        transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    .apply_now, .apply_direct, .preview input[type="button"], .links > input.continue {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6A8CB1 !important;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        font: 400 11px Arial;
        margin: 0 5px 17px 0;
        outline: 3px none;
        padding: 8px 14px !important;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    a {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why not target IE7 with conditional comments - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Is there a reason `div.jobpost_body h2 a` is floated left? that may be causing it to appear to the left of the p element. That css seriously needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: The problem is there are multiple style sheets because of the design of our system. Some of the style sheets I cannot edit as they are inaccessible meaning If I generate an IE7 only style sheet the chances are that anything I put in it will be overwritten by the underlying system. I hate IE7 and have had to cater especially for it before with a separate style sheet but in this case it's not a possibility. I will therefore need to know how I can refactor the code above to work in IE7 and all browsers that followed...

Comment: @KevinB That is from the underlying system that we have and even if I disable it in Firebug it makes no difference. Also how does the css need cleaning up? That is pasted directly from Firebug, I have written everything in order in my css file.

Comment: well, for one, count how many times and how many different ways you target the `div.jobpost_body`

Comment: @KevinB And your point is? If I'm overwriting other stylesheets then there are obviously going to be multiple declarations there.

Comment: Removing the float from the a may not be enough. Basically what i'm getting at is the default styles on a lot of that html will do what you want it to do without modification. My guess is that whatever you are overriding is adding styles to those and you are trying to override those styles. We can't see those styles, so it's going to be tough to help you override them. **Is the css you posted the only css that is affecting this page?**

Comment: What I think @KevinB meant was that the HTML/CSS is large and requires some good time to debug. It would be better if you isolate the CSS and provide a more cleaner or even a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The CSS I posted is only the CSS that is effecting all of the elements within the html snippet I have provided. The CSS was taken from Firebug with 'Only show applied styles' turned on. I know the code is quite messy as 1. I haven't coded in CSS for 2 years and 2. Most of the underlying code is out of my control but the CSS can be tidied up later on. What is most important right now is getting it working in IE7.

Comment: What parts of that css CAN you modify. Split it up into two parts: your css, and the css that you can't touch. Is the css that you can't touch applied via style attributes? a stylesheet? All of these things are important to consider when trying to override styles.

Comment: Just make a fiddle mate and I am sure you will find good enough answers in no time.

Comment: @Jawad You mean in the code snippet? That's just the way the StackOverflow handles it. At the end of the day i've provided all of the html and css that is required which is a lot more than some people on here would do.

Comment: The CSS I can't touch is applied by several stylesheets hidden away within the underlying system. Everything works correctly in IE8 onwards just not iE7.

Comment: "which is a lot more than some people on here would do" come on mate. You are not competing with other people for the "Good Question Asked" trophy. All I am saying is that debugging takes a lot of time and efforts and it would help people a lot which would in turn help you. Take a break, get a drink, inhale some cig's and chill. You do this for them, they do the answers for you.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your code, it doesn't look exactly the same, but it shows the same problem. http://jsfiddle.net/8VZuc/

Comment: If you get rid of floatLeft on the `h2 a` in both places, it works. http://jsfiddle.net/8VZuc/2/ if you can't get rid of it in both, override it with `float: none` where you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the float from `h2 a` in both places.

```
    div.jobpost {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
div.jobpost {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-size: 100%;
    outline: 0 none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

div.jobpost div.jobpost_body {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.jobpost_body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#icams_inserted {
    color: #6D7A7E !important;
    font-family: Arial !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
html.ext-strict body {
    text-align: left !important;
}
body {
    color: #6D7A7E;
}

.jobpost_body h2 {
    font-family: Arial,'Adamina',serif !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.25;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #606163;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Arial,'Adamina',serif;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
}


div.jobpost_body h2 a {
    border: 0 solid #FF0000;
    display: block;
    /*float: left;*/ /* <---- HERE */
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.not-ie a, .not-ie a > * {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
a, a > * {
    color: #6D7A7E;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: medium none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}


div.jobpost_body h2 a {
    border: 0 solid #FF0000;
    display: block;
    /*float: left;*/ /* <---- HERE */
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.not-ie a, .not-ie a > * {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
a, a > * {
    color: #6D7A7E;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: medium none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

div.jobpost_body p.jobpost_classifications {
    border: 0 none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
div.jobpost_body p {
    clear: none !important;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
div.jobpost_body p {
    clear: left;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.jobpost_body p {
    color: #6D7A7E;
    font: 400 12px/19px Arial;
}
p {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}


.jobclass {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

.jobclass_type {
    color: #6D7A7E;
    font: 700 12px/18px Arial;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.jobclass_type {
    color: #6D7A7E;
    font: 700 12px/18px Arial;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


div.jobpost_nav {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 6px !important;
    width: 100%;
}


div.jobpost_nav p {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}


div.jobpost_nav a.apply_direct, div.jobpost_nav a.job_basket, div.jobpost_nav a.send_a_friend {
    padding: 8px 14px !important;
}
div.jobpost_nav a.apply_direct, div.jobpost_nav a.job_basket, div.jobpost_nav a.send_a_friend {
    float: left;
}
div.jobpost_nav a.apply_direct, div.jobpost_nav a.job_basket, div.jobpost_nav a.send_a_friend {
    padding: 0 20px 0 0 !important;
    width: auto;
}
.not-ie a, .not-ie a > * {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s, border 0.2s ease 0s, color 0.2s ease 0s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.apply_now, .apply_direct, .preview input[type="button"], .links > input.continue {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6A8CB1 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 400 11px Arial;
    margin: 0 5px 17px 0;
    outline: 3px none;
    padding: 8px 14px !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow. I'm so stupid. That has worked. Overridden and now it's sitting nicely in IE7. Sorry I was a bit snappy, it's been a long day and I'm fed up of working with this system and it's flaws :-(

Comment: Now the only issue is the button isn't displaying the same. Any ideas?

Comment: @jme1988 - IE7 doesn't recognize `display: inline-block`. You'll need to override it with `display: block` so that it will recognize it as an element that can heed margins/padding.